# Rails 4: How to display fields with error in red?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

**First question**: how to validate a model relation and mark it in form when validation failed.

I have a subject model:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base     
  belongs_to :semester
  validates_presence_of :semester  
end
```

In my view (form):

```
<%= select_tag :semester, options_from_collection_for_select(@semesters,"id","name") %>
```

The `validates_presence_of` works fine. But when the validation fails (user forgot to enter semester ). The semester input is not marked in red.

**Second question**: how to validate an input field.

In my view, I also have a university input field, but model subject has no relationship with university, no field university in subject table. So how to validate it and mark it in red.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# app/models/subject.rb
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base     
  belongs_to :semester
  validates :semester, :university, presence: true # new syntax http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates
end

# app/views/subjects/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @subject do |f| %>
  Semestr: <%= f.collection_select :semester_id, Semestr.all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  University: <%= f.text_field :univercity %>
<% end %>
```

For more information about building forms in rails (with validations enabled) you could find there http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html

Comment: That answers my first question. Thanks.

But I get this error: undefined method `university' for #<Subject:0x007fb09d8d9f00>

Comment: No relation with Subject. But university has relation with semesters. So I need user to select university first and then semester.

Comment: `has_many :universities, though: semesters`  ? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the fields with error displayed in red "out of the box", you must use a [form builder](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form). The code will looks like `f.select ...` instead of using `select_tag`.

With the form builder, the fields with errors are created inside a `<div class="field_with_errors">...</div>`. The css file generated by scaffolding displays these fields in red; if you're not using it, you must add the css rules to your css.

Answer (score 0):

Those "red errors" that you hope for are probably coming from a form helper gem like [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), feel free to check that out.

I have literally no idea what your second question is asking, but if you're looking for a custom validation. Check out the [rails docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) on them for help.

If you'd like more help, (please) edit your question to be more clear (thanks)

Comment: I tried to validate a university input field that has no relationship with subject. When I put `validates :university, presence: true` in model. I got this error: `undefined method university' for #<Subject:0x007fb09d8d9f00>` because there is no university field in subject.